# How do I install updates after dismissing the popup?

Tags: updates, icons, update-manager

The update green icon is the icon that pop-up and informs that you can install updates, or you can choose to be informed later.

I wanted to install them now, but I accidentally clicked "Remind me later", instead of "Install now".

How to summon the icon again so I can do the right thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called "Software Updater". You can open it from the dash:

[image]

It will then check for updates and let you install them, as well as change update related settings.

Comment: hi, what if I don't see the dash interface? I can use it if I switch to console, but I'm using vnc/xfce4 window and don't see dash. How can can summon the Software Updater?

Comment: @chan If you're running xfce4 you probably have a little mouse button (the "whisker" menu) that you can search from. Let me know if that works. I'm not at my PC right now, but if it doesn't work I'll find a more exact answer later.

Comment: I found the Applications tab at the top left of Xfce4 window. (when I asked earlied, I believe it wasn't there. I updated softare and reboot, and it's back on there. maybe I'm mistaking..). and there I see System-Software Updater pull down menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can run updates via terminal as well  using the commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I was looking for Seth's answer, but I will give you a +1 for answering.

Comment: One should prefer `apt-get upgrade` over `apt-get dist-upgrade` whenever it's not necessarily needed...

Comment: @byte the GUI uses dist-upgrade so I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: I don't know what exactly which GUI does, but `dist-upgrade` allows it to both install new or also remove old packages if it thinks that is needed. @Seth